# Best way to trim off the time from this date

Tags: jquery, regex, time, trim, slice

I have a date string that looks like this coming from an RSS feed...

```
Thu, 03 Oct 2013 05:00:00 GMT
```

And I'm wanting to take off the time stamp + GMT.

I am using this now for the GMT part...

```
.replace('GMT', '');
```

But I'm wondering if there is a regular expression that I need to use or if a simple trim or slice can help me out here. I just can't quite think through the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
.slice(0, -4);  // This will remove the last 4 character in the string.
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
str.replace(/ \d\d:\d\d:\d\d GMT/, '');
```

This will remove the time part of date time string.

`\d`  stands for any digit from 0 to 9.

**explanation of regex:**

```
The regular expression:

 \d\d:\d\d:\d\d GMT

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                           ' '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   GMT                     ' GMT'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Comment: I like this, thank you so much. I think for now the .slice() answer will do because I'll always be getting the same amount of characters from the RSS feed. But in the case where that doesn't work I will remember this. I've been meaning to take a short RegEx course to be able to understand how it works and when best to use it.